# Why does this code give segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote a small example to test my understanding of pointers and memory, however I was sure this would work but then it gave seg fault... Any idea what I am doing wrong? **Add: I ran this code with other code.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Card {

  int a;
  Card(int a) : a(a) { }

};

int main() {

  int **p;
  int **p2;
  int *a;
  int b =3;
  char ** cArray;
  Card **c = new Card*[5];
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
     c[i] = new Card(1);


  a = &b;
  for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    p = &a;
    //  p2[i] = new int;
    *(cArray + i) = "string";
    cout << cArray[i]<< endl;
  }



  for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    // p2[i] = a; 
    cout << *a << endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: It works for me - what compiler and OS are you using ? Can you post the actual seg fault message ?

Comment: @Mark-Other than memory leaks, nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: This does not segfault for me (on g++/Linux).

Comment: Works alright here... are you sure you copy/pasted correctly?

Comment: I could not find the source of segfault. I thought it was because of Card because when I removed it, the segfault is gone...

Comment: what OS are you on? If you are on linux, you can get a `core dump` and then debug using the core dump in gdb/ddd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char ** cArray;
```

`cArray` is an unintialized pointer to pointer. You cannot de-reference it.

```
*(cArray + i) = "string";
```

Comment: How come when I removed the Card part from main there was no seg fault?

Comment: Segmentation faults are run-time errors that has undefined behavior. If you are unlucky, it behaves as if every thing went correct.

Answer (score 1):

`cArray` uninitialized. Correct this.

```
char ** cArray = new char*[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

cArray variable does not seem to be initialised.